# Categorical products are associative

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category with products, and let $A, B, C \in \mathbf{C}$. I wish to show that there exists a morphism $h: (A \times B) \times C \to A \times (B \times C)$ which is an isomorphism.

I believe I can get that we have morphisms $g_1:(A \times B) \times C \to A \times (B \times C)$ and $g_2:A \times (B \times C) \to (A \times B) \times C$ and that they are the unique morphisms satisfying the universal property for products.

However, I don't see how to show that one/either of them is an isomorphism. We need to prove that their compositions are identity morphisms on those product objects. This amounts to showing that for any objects $U, V, W, X$ and arrows
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_U&: U \to (A \times B) \times C \\
f_V&: (A \times B) \times C \to V \\
f_W&: W \to A \times (B \times C) \\
f_X&: A \times (B \times C) \to X \\
\end{aligned}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
(g_2 \circ g_1) \circ f_U &= f_U \\
f_V \circ (g_2 \circ g_1) &= f_V \\
(g_1 \circ g_2) \circ f_W &= f_W \\
f_X \circ (g_1 \circ g_2) &= f_X.
\end{aligned}
$$
The first two equalities above assert that $g_2 \circ g_1 = \mathrm{id}_{(A \times B) \times C}$, and the second pair asserts that $g_1 \circ g_2 = \mathrm{id}_{A \times (B \times C)}$. From here, though, I am stuck.

Comment: Couldn’t you prove that both (A+B)+C and A+(B+C) are both coproducts of A,B, and C. Then by universal mapping property, $(A+B)+C/cong A+(B+C)$

Answer (score 2):

See 1.5 "Diagram Chasing" here https://compose.ioc.ee/categoryTheory2020/week3/week3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** As in the comments, prove that both $(A\times B)\times C$ and $A\times (B\times C)$ are limits for the discrete 3-point diagram $A,B,C$ (ternary product).