# Product associativity in category theory

Tags: category-theory

The same question is given here [Categorical products are associative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4027071/455950), however, one of the answers uses concepts not introduced yet in my book, and the other provides a link (https://compose.ioc.ee/categoryTheory2020/week3/week3.pdf, "Diagram Chasing") which to me is still unclear. I am trying to prove $A \times (B \times C) \cong (A \times B) \times C$

Basically, the answer in the link states that we can form the following four commuting diagrams:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

From these we have the diagram:

[image]

Then the author concludes that because this arrow is unique, it must be the identity arrow. This is the part that I do not follow. Where in the proof have we concluded that $q_2 \circ q_1$ makes the last diagram commute? Once that is established then I understand how we can conclude $q_2 \circ q_1 = 1_{A(BC)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commutativity of the last diagram follows from the commutativities of the previous four diagrams.

For the left-hand triangle we have
$$
 p_{A2} ∘ q_2 ∘ q_1
 = p_{A1} ∘ p_{AB} ∘ q_1
 = p_{A1} ∘ q_{AB}
 = p_{A2}
$$
by the definition of $q_2$, the definition of $q_2$, and the definition of $q_{AB}$.

For the right-hand triangle we have
\begin{align*}
 p_{BC} ∘ q_2 ∘ q_1
 &= q_{BC} ∘ q_1 \tag{$1$} \\
 &= ⟨p_{B1} ∘ p_{AB}, p_{C1}⟩ ∘ q_1 \tag{$2$} \\
 &= ⟨p_{B1} ∘ p_{AB} ∘ q_1, p_{C1} ∘ q_1⟩ \\
 &= ⟨p_{B1} ∘ q_{AB}, p_{C2} ∘ p_{BC}⟩ \tag{$3$} \\
 &= ⟨p_{B2} ∘ p_{BC}, p_{C2} ∘ p_{BC}⟩ \tag{$4$} \\
 &= ⟨p_{B2}, p_{C2}⟩ ∘ p_{BC} \\
 &= 1_{BC} ∘ p_{BC} \\
 &= p_{BC} \,,
\end{align*}
where for $(1)$ we use the definition of $q_2$, for $(2)$ we use the definition of $q_{BC}$, for $(3)$ we use the definition of $q_1$, for $(4)$ we use the definition of $q_{AB}$.